# Nginx reduce repeat directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have bunch of location directive in my Nginx config and most of them have same `add_header`, is there any way that I can introduce variable in nginx or any generator for all this config? specially for `location` directive.

is there any way to set default for `add_header` so stop repeating in each `location` directive?

here is 3 locations out of 50 directive in my config:

```
location ^~ /example/1/ {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.113:8124/geoserver/ws/wms;
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control private;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    add_header Expires -1;
}

location ^~ /example-org {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.199:9126/geoserver/wms;
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control private;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    add_header Expires -1;
}

location ^~ /example-org/1 {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.199:18124/geoserver/wms;
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control private;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    add_header Expires -1;
}
```

**edit #1** (after `Richard Smith` comment)

```
add_header Pragma no-cache;
add_header Cache-Control private;
add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
add_header Cache-Control no-store;
add_header Expires -1;

location ^~ /example/1/ {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.113:8124/geoserver/ws/wms;
    
}

location ^~ /example-org {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.199:9126/geoserver/wms;
}

location ^~ /example-org/1 {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.199:18124/geoserver/wms;
}
```

Comment: Move them to the outer block and they will be inherited by each of the `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) for details.

Comment: something like `edit #1`?